# Unexpected black lines on the edge of a RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, regions, computational-geometry

I want to create the following 3D solid object, which is an octahedron, cutting by six spheres centered at its vertices.

The code is as:

```
RegionPlot3D[-2 x + 2 y - 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 
   0 && -2 x - 2 y - 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 0 && 
  2 x - 2 y - 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 0 && 2 x + 2 y - 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 0 && 
  2 x + 2 y + 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 0 && -2 x + 2 y + 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 0 &&
   2 x - 2 y + 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 0 && -2 x - 2 y + 2 z + Sqrt[2] >= 0
  && (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - x)^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 1/4 && 
  x^2 + (1/Sqrt[2] - y)^2 + z^2 > 1/4 && 
  x^2 + y^2 + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - z)^2 > 1/4 && 
  x^2 + y^2 + (1/Sqrt[2] - z)^2 > 1/4 && 
  x^2 + (-(1/Sqrt[2]) - y)^2 + z^2 > 
   1/4 && (1/Sqrt[2] - x)^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 1/4, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
  1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 250, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

and the output looks like:
[image]

There are moustache like black lines on the edge. Increase the `PlotPoints` option to 250 cannot remove it.

**Update:**

Outputs with `BoundaryStyle->None`:
[image]

How can I obtain desired smooth version of the solid? Why such black lines happen?

Comment: Try `BoundaryStyle -> None`.

Comment: The lines still exist but turn into white or something transparent.

Comment: I've found `Region`s to be a bit unreliable when they get really thin like that. An adaptive mesh approach, using `DiscretizeRegion` with an appropriate `MeshRefinementFunction` could do the trick. Have a look at [105756](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105756/meshrefinementfunction-missing-points), and see if it helps.

Comment: Using [`contourRegionPlot3D[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530) on this problem gives [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F5nWS.png).

Comment: Thank you @J.M. , this new function via ContourPlot3D solves my problem. By increasing PlotPoints into 80 or so, the output graph looks pretty good. contourRegionPlot3D is much better than the built-in RegionPlot3D in these aspects if 3D solid model is not needed